# Image is not getting uploaded with JSF 2.0 PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2

I want to upload an image with PrimeFaces and jsf.
Image is not getting uploaded even PrimeFaces tag looks like good also validating the image size and type.

My web.xml configuration

```
   <filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
    <param-value>5120000</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>  
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name> 
    <param-value>D:\tmp</param-value> 
</init-param>
</filter>
```

My PrimeFaces code in my xhtml

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{itemBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"  
              update="messages" sizeLimit="10000000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />  

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

ItemBean code

```
private String destination="D:\\tempt\\";

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    System.out.println("going to file upload");
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    // Do what you want with the file        
    try {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}  

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
       try {


            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            System.out.println("New file created!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```

............................